# view subcategories order by id

Tags: order, terms

this code to display subcategories in categories page

i need to view subcategories sort as id subcategories
can anyone update this code to view subcategories order by id

```
<?php
if(is_category()) {

    $breakpoint = 0;
    $thiscat = get_term( get_query_var('cat') , 'category' );
    $subcategories = get_terms( 'category' , 'parent='.get_query_var('cat') );

    $items='';
    if(!empty($subcategories)) {
        foreach($subcategories as $subcat) {
            if($thiscat->term_id == $subcat->term_id) $current = ' current-cat'; else $current = '';
        $items .= '

             <span class="sidebar_content_morzak"><a href="'.get_category_link( $subcat->term_id ).'" title="">'.$subcat->name.'</a></span>


         ';
        }
        echo "$items";
    }
    unset($subcategories,$subcat,$thiscat,$items);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to order by `id` you can replace

```
 $subcategories = get_terms( 'category' , 'parent='.get_query_var('cat') );
```

with

```
 $args=array(
     'parent'=>get_query_var('cat'),
     'orderby' => 'id', 
     'order' => 'ASC',  
 );
 $subcategories = get_terms( 'category' , $args);
```

You can read more about the available parameters in the Codex here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term

Comment: ok great it worked out for you ;-)

Comment: ps: you should consider marking the question as resolved, thanks ;-)